# Elasticsearch 5.5 - how to return _all.total.store.size_in_bytes from _stats ?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have Elastic 5.5 and want to create query, which returns size of the index with wildcars in index name.

Index name: `eltrack-*cps*`

What I have tried:

```
GET /eltrack-*cps*/_stats/_all.total.store.size_in_bytes
GET /_cat/indices/eltrack-*cps*
{
  "_source": "_all.total.store.size_in_bytes" 
}
```

None of this works, meaning it throws `illegal_argument_exception`.

Do you have suggestions ? Thanks in response :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `GET /eltrack-*cps*/_stats/store` (maybe with `?human` added) not good enough? Not sure you can filter down to just that one specific field, but the relevant information is in that query (plus additional data for other sizes).

Comment: Hi, since I want only this field; I wanted to get as atomic response from server as possible. It would save me some time parsing and make the code more clear. But as you say, query you provided may be the closest I can get. Thanks :)